Sci-fi movie 90-05: female prisoner went to spaceship, a room full of naked girls
The main actress was from somewhere in the galaxy like a prison planet, then she went to a spaceship. The female scientist there was affected by an alien in one mission and now she's trying to make everyone in the spaceship pregnant with aliens just by touching (?). There's a scene with a lot of naked girls in the room and she's making out with them. It seems only one male actor in that movie and he had sex (maybe?) with the main prisoner girl, but he died.
I have been looking for this old movie for very long time. I watched it on DVD.

In roughly which year did you watch this? 2005?

This movie sounds classy as heck. Possibly one of Oliver Stone's early works, before JFK

A bit similar to The Outer Limits, S04E23, The Origin of Species

What does "90-05" mean in the question title?

@OrganicMarble, probably 1990 to 2005
